# Weird error 500

Tags: error

I'm new to CiviCRM, so please bear with me. I inherited a functioning site with a CiviCRM install (on Wordpress) that was working properly. They asked me to change the domain in use, and after I attempted and failed to make that work I set everything (or at least I thought I got everything) back to how it was on the original domain. I thought everything was working fine, but now certain pages from with CiviCRM fail to load, but most work fine. I tried a bunch of different items in the header bar, but the following fail with an error 500:

Draft and Unscheduled Mailings
Scheduled and Sent Mailings

I checked the http access.log file and I didn't see anything relevant other than the reported 500 error. Any idea how to diagnose and fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the http `error.log` (as opposed to access.log)? Usually there's more messages about 500 errors in there, like what the actual PHP error is and what file/line it's happening on. If it seems like this might require some back and forth, stackexchange isn't great for that and you might get better help at chat.civicrm.org in the user-support channel.

Comment: Can you close the loop and post your own answer? Based on the chat comments it sounded like the problem was that the site was Civi version 4.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a civicrm version 4.7 bug. I have no idea why it didn't crop up before, the site was like that for years. The solution, as recommended by folks in the chat, was to update to the latest release. The is fully up to date now and working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Of course the way stackexchange works now you have wait 2 more days before you can actually click the checkmark to finalize the answer, but what can you do...

Comment: Oh I guess 2 days from first posting the Q not the A. Learned something new!